# overlapping subreports in pentaho report designer

Tags: layout, height, pentaho, subreport, report-designer

I'm having trouble using multiple sub-reports in pentaho.
It works fine when the number of records in a sub-report is low (less than 10) but when it has more than 10 records the sub-reports overlap each other so nothing can be read.

and when I increase the height of sub-reports then none of the sub-reports can be visible.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I know of is using sub-reports in banded mode, instead of inline. If they're banded, they'll grow as much as required.

however, you cannot have banded sub-reports take only part of the available width. To overcome this you may need to nest several levels of sub-reports.

Comment: Thanks for help I did what you said. I used 3 banded sub-reports and in each of them (in the report header section) I put 2 inline sub-reports. but the upper subreports still overlap with the middle one.

Comment: You may need to explore the idea a bit further and try to get a good enough engine. Try changing the height, preferred-height and max-height attributes.